# Removing an Item from Magento's Admin Panel Navigation

Tags: php, xml, magento, navigation, overriding

Using the Magento Ecommerce system, is is possible to remove an item from the Admin Panel Navigation menu?  More generally, is there a way to use the config override system to *remove* existing elements from a configuration?

I know I can add to the navigation with an override that looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>
                0.1.0
            </version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
             <cms translate="title" module="cms">
                <title>The CMS</title>
                <sort_order>70</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <foo translate="title" module="cms">
                        <title>Foo Item</title>
                        <action>adminhtml/foo</action>
                    </foo>
                </children>
             </cms>
        </menu>    
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

but how would/could I completely suppress the CMS navigation item?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cleaner way to do this:

Add a **adminhtml.xml** (e.g. to an existing modules that keeps all other customization stuff, or create a new module)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <xmlconnect>
            <disabled>1</disabled>
        </xmlconnect>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to handle things in a modern version of Magento.  I'm not sure if it's supported in older version, but if you're having trouble see the old, original accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/769931/4668

Answer (score 11):

You could inject a bogus module dependency into the menu item in your config.xml.

In your case,

```
<adminhtml>
  <menu>
    <cms translate="title" module="cms">
      <depends><module>HideMe</module></depends>
    </cms>
  </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Your science impresses me!  Will depends work like that in other areas of the config file?  I'd only even seen it used to ensure correct module loading order.

Comment: It seems to be only for initializing Magento's modules (as you stated) and building the adminhtml menu.  Module dependencies seem to be checked in these classes:

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu
Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config
Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Admin_Page
Mage_Api_Model_Config
Mage_Core_Model_Config

Comment: @Alan and @Scott just wondering if either of you found a more elegant way of doing this in the two years since posting. It seems a little ... hacky (no offense intended!). Thanks, JD

Comment: @JonathanDay It looks like modern version of Magento support a <disabled>1</disabled> node to turn a menu (or ACL rule) on/off.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Alan would still need anyone to ask this question, but for anyone else that might end up reading this, it would be a bit better to use:

```
<adminhtml>
  <menu>
    <cms translate="title" module="cms">
      <depends><config>some/configuration/flag</config></depends>
    </cms>
  </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a specific menu point you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <customer>
            <children>
                <online>
                    <disabled>1</disabled>
                </online>
            </children>
        </customer>
    </menu>
</config>
```