# magento remove admin menu item

Tags: php, xml, magento, admin

Is it possible, in magento, to remove a menu item in admin?

I have a new module and am pulling the reviews and ratings into a new section. I'm not opposed to leaving them also in the catalog section, but if its possible (and clean) I'd like to nip it out of there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing an Item from Magento's Admin Panel Navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723828/removing-an-item-from-magentos-admin-panel-navigation)

Answer (score 15):

Add next lines to extension config.xml file:

```
<adminhtml>
   <menu>
      <catalog>
         <children>
            <reviews_ratings>
               <disabled>1</disabled>
            </reviews_ratings>
         </children>
      </catalog>
   </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

And clear the cache.

Comment: What  should be folder structure in Custom module ? Which files i need to create inside local folder? This is Not proper answer

Comment: Read topic question again please, @veilig wrote "I have a new module", so he already has module with needed structure and config.xml file. This file can be found in 'etc' module folder.

Comment: But you can help others by specifying how such structure can be created. Thankks !

Comment: and You DID not specify what you did in ur code. Just pasting code is not proper. Write what the tags in xml means.

Comment: Magento Module creation process is fully described in official documentation on Magento site, repeat whole article here don't make any sense. And about xml code in my answer - it's fully self descriptive - I don't see anything what should be described.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi if you have another question, you should ask it separately. This question is not about module structure.

Comment: Very old question but stumbled upon it. I'm going to have to agree with @ToxaBes on this. The user already stated they have a module. Magento follows specific conventions, and the question is not "how to build a module". My only feedback at this point is that this question should be updated to state "the extension's `adminhtml.xml`" file, and the XML slightly restructured to conform to Magento 1's more recent conventions.