# Magento remove "Promo" Item

Tags: php, magento

How do I remove the whole "Promo" menu item from the Admin menu?
It seems to be no separate module.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723828/removing-an-item-from-magentos-admin-panel-navigation / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049517/magento-remove-admin-menu-item

Comment: Yes, I've already found this topics. However, I can't find any XML file for this module. So I'm specifically looking for how to remove the "Promo" item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1** - Using local.xml

Open /app/etc/local.xml and add the 'adminhtml' tag below

```
<config>
    <global> 
        .....
    </global>
    <admin>
        ....
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
          <promo translate="title" module="promo">
            <depends><module>HideMe</module></depends>
          </promo>
        </menu>
     </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**Method 2** - Creating a Custom Module

Create /app/code/local/MagePal/RemovePromoMenu/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
   <modules>
        <MagePal_RemovePromoMenu>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </MagePal_RemovePromoMenu>
   </modules
   <adminhtml>
        <menu>
          <promo translate="title" module="promo">
            <disabled>1</disabled>
          </promo>
        </menu>
   </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Create /app/etc/modules/MagePal_RemovePromoMenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePal_RemovePromoMenu>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MagePal_RemovePromoMenu>
    </modules>
</config>
```

@dsueiro [Removing an Item from Magento's Admin Panel Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723828/removing-an-item-from-magentos-admin-panel-navigation)

Comment: There was no such folder like "RWS" in "local" so I created it and put your code in there. But it doesn't work, the Promo is still there. What may I have done wrong?

Comment: so I have the magento main directory and than: app/code/local/RWS/RemovePromoMenu/etc/config.xml (I also tried with "locale" instead of "local" but without success as well). I also emptied the entire cache. Promo is still there

Comment: To create a module in magento you also need to create a config file in /app/etc/modules. I update my code above to reflex this... You may also want to reading how to create magento module @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento