# How to remove theme tab name from magento

Tags: magento, themes

I am using Queldorei theme after installation it create its custom tab on top just beside system tab.
How can i remove this?
I do not want to remove theme.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to theme module config.xml file, in this file find `<menu>` tag and comment this `<menu>` tag

after doing this clear your cache and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. Comment out the `<menu>` in either `adminhtml.xml` or `config.xml`
2. Removing it using `local.xml` or a custom module (if you want to avoid making changes to that modules) see [Magento remove "Promo" Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720431/magento-remove-promo-item)