# Hide admin menu items

Tags: magento

I have seen quite a bit of posts about hiding menu items in admin, the method I chose was to create a custom module and disable it through there - which seemed like the most elegant way of doing this. But I can't quite seem to get it to work. Here is what I did:

File: app/etc/modules/LDW_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <LDW_AdminMenu>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </LDW_AdminMenu>
    </modules>
</config>
```

File: app/code/local/LDW/AdminMenu/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <LDW_AdminMenu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </LDW_AdminMenu>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <mobile>
                <depends><module>HideMe</module></depends>
            </mobile>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Source:
http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/21/magento-how-to-hide-menu-items-of-admin-panel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look @ [Magento remove "Promo" Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720431/magento-remove-promo-item)

Since you put your code in the community folder and not local (code pool)

Your need to change your codePool in app/etc/modules/ from

```
<codePool>local</codePool>
```

To

```
<codePool>community</codePool>
```

Also rename your xml file

> app/etc/modules/LDW.xml

to

> app/etc/modules/LDW_AdminMenu.xml (or LDW_All.xml)

In config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <LDW_AdminMenu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </LDW_AdminMenu>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <xmlconnect>
                <disabled>1</disabled>
            </xmlconnect>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks. More I think about it, does it actually belong in local and not community? I might have done that out of confusion between the two folders.

Comment: Check out the code above, I moved it into local and updated with some of the changes in the article you linked and it's still appearing.

Comment: Try renaming adminhtml.xml to config.xml or add a config.xml and copy `<modules>`... `<\modules>` from adminhtml.xml to the new config.xml

Comment: Ok, that works but not for the <mobile> menu item, however other menus hide successfully. Do you know what module this item is coming from?

Comment: See /app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/etc/adminhtml.xml. Try `<xmlconnect>` instead of `<mobile>`